# using ImmutableMultiDict with the new dict version of python

Tags: python, flask

I have a request.args that is ImmutableMultiDict, which means that some keys appears more than once, for example:

```
[('email', 'abc@gmail.com'), ('service', 'first'), ('service', 'second'), ('service', 'third')]
```

When I used the dict function in Python 3.6.3 and called:

```
dict(request.args)
```

I got:

```
{'email':['abc@gmail.com'], 'service':['first','second','third']}
```

So I could iterate over the different values of services using:

```
dict(request.args)['service']
```

But after I upgrade to the python 3.6.8, the `dict(request.args)` returns:

```
{'email': 'abc@gmail.con', 'service': 'first'}
```

and I lost all the other values of the service key.

Does anyone have an idea how to iterate those values using Python 3.6.8? Doing a simple `request.args.get('service')` also returns only the first matching element.

Comment: Tried `request.args.getlist('service')`?

Comment: please format the question. its unreadable

Comment: It is working with getlist! Thanks!